# Java webapp Filter causes failure to startup server on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, servlet-filters

I have 3 applications up on my Tomcat and everything worked fine leading up to this mess.
Before I begin, I am in need of reconfiguring my tomcat logging as this may not be working, but I feel that my application fails to start for a reason that could be put down to erroneous configuring of a Filter I implemented as a first timer today:

```
package org.thejarbar.web.filters;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public final class JSessionFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfigObj) {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest _req, ServletResponse _res,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) _req;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) _res;
        String url =req.getRequestURL().toString();

        if(Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("jsessionid"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(url).find()){

            String redirectURL = "http://thejarbar.org";
            res.setStatus(res.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
            res.setHeader("Location",redirectURL);
            res.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void destroy() { }
}
```

Configured in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.thejarbar.web.filters.JSessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I suspect a memory issue, but don't know what command to run on my Unix guest for this, and deleting my biggest application next to my main application does not resolve this (this should free up enough resources).

Is there anything visible in what I posted that could be to blame and rectified?
The applications:[enter link description here](http://thejarbar.org) and [enter link description here](http://buhaugane.com) seem to be deployed but can't be accessed (if you try).

On my development system all runs smoothly.

**Edit** Managed to get a log file up again:

```
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | Jun 23, 2012 1:19:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | SEVERE: Catalina.start:
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:624)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp.run(WrapperStartStopApp.java:264)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
INFO | jvm 1 | 2012/06/23 01:19:58 | at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Comment: are you getting any errors (or) exceptions?

Comment: @ thinksteep not in my log no (which may be broken) as I messed it up. The applications appear to be deployed though because if you try access them by links I provided you don't get any response/timeout. I think I deleted my tomcat log andmay have fixed it wrongly 2 years ago due to mental illness. How can I ensure Tomcat log is set up? I have many log files by date in logs and no errors in todays log...

Comment: Removing my filter mapping allows all applications to start

Comment: Which `web.xml` did you modify?

Comment: The one for my main site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my issue. My hosting provider has outdated documentation of where my tomcat logging is found. Namely my `catalina.out` was under `var/log/tomcat7` location and nowhere under `/opt/tomcat7`.

Viewing the logs I saw `UnsupportedClassVersion` Exception and downloaded a jdk that matches my production environment. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

If your "main site" file is Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` then you are editing the wrong file. Put `conf/web.xml` back the way it was (or download a fresh copy from `tomcat.apache.org`) and then edit your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` file instead. That way, your `Filter` will be loaded from your webapp's `WEB-INF/classes` or `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` instead of trying to load it for *all applications* from Tomcat's `lib/` directory. Obviously, you need to make sure that your `org/thejarbar/web/filters/JSessionFilter.class` is either in `WEB-INF/classes` or in a JAR file in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Also note that you are doing more work in your Filter than strictly necessary: you don't need to...

1. Compile a regular expression pattern for every request (do it once)
2. Use a regular expression pattern *at all* (you can use a simple substring search)
3. You should probably be looking for `;jsessionid=` if you really don't want to accept URLs with embedded session ids
4. You need a `return` statement in there, otherwise you will return a `Redirect` plus *still* process the original request
5. There is an API method that can already tell you what you want to know (see below)

Try this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest _req, ServletResponse _res,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) _req;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) _res;

    if(request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL())
    {
        String redirectURL = "http://thejarbar.org";
        res.setStatus(res.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        res.setHeader("Location",redirectURL);
        res.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
    }
    else
    {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

That should work infinitely better than what you originally posted.

Comment: My web.xml(s) are per application and my war has been tested locally, so I can safely say that it's in the classpath. Do you know how I can rebuild Tomcat logging perhaps? I am missing catalina.out.

Comment: This Filter is to fix SEO errors from old requests and all my .wars come with own .web.xml (I am not touching the one in Tomcat). Do you know how I can repair catalina.out?

Comment: I did and thank you... I saw that latest reports from Google. Thanks to you I made changes, but without the method provided from the Java API as it's documentation is unclear, so I rolled my own...